# How to write a function that automatically creates for...in loops depending on the number of nests in a multidimensional object?

Tags: javascript

```
function hierarchy() {
    list = {    
        "cat": {
            "color": "red",
            "family": {
                "mother": "jesus",
                "father": "mary"
            }
        },
        "dog": {
            "color": "blue",
            "family": {
                "mother": "harold"   
            }
        },
        "bird": {
            "color": "orange"
        },
        "pokemon": {
            "color": "green",
            "family": {
                "mother": "fdajs",
                "brothers": {
                    1: "james",
                    2: "what"
                }
            }
        }
    };

    for (levelOne in list) {
        for (levelTwo in list[levelOne]) {
            if (levelTwo === "color") {
                console.log(levelTwo+" "+list[levelOne][levelTwo]);   
            }
            if (levelTwo === "family") {
                for (levelThree in list[levelOne][levelTwo]) {    
                    console.log(levelTwo+" "+"("+levelThree+") "+list[levelOne][levelTwo[levelThree]); 
                }
            }
            if (//if properties and objects are added to list they should be automatically detected here) {
                for (this.level in this.parent.level) {
                    console.log(list[firstChild][this.level]
                }
            } 
            for (this.level in list[firstChild][secondChild]) {
                for (etc...) {
                    for (etc...) {

                        }
                }
            }     
       }
    }
}
```

This is the procedural version in pseudo code of the function I want to make. If I edit the list object to include more properties or even more nested objects, how can I create a recursive function that self-detects when an object.hasOwnProperty such that it then creates more for...in loops regardless of the name of the property of the nested objects?

```
function createNewLevel() {
    for (this.level in myObject) {
        if (this.object.hasOwnProperty(//list child properties and objects) {
           //for every property, do something
            //for every nested object, instantiate new createNewLevel(this.level)
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe it's something like this pseudo code? There's probably some methods I'm not familiar with that can fetch parent and child objects as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a typical recursive problem:

```
var path = [];
function f(obj) {
    var k;
    for (k in obj) {
        path.push(k);
        if (!(typeof obj[k] === 'object')) {
            console.log(path.join('.') + ': ' + obj[k]);
        } else {
            f(obj[k]);
        }
        path.pop();
    }
}

f(list);
```

Comment: @discardthis - np, could you also vote up if that's helpful to you, thanks.